# jQuery if statement not catching #ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to write a simple conditional statement that checks an element's ID to identify it when dropped onto another element and something is tripping me up... Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4kvev05a/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="droppable" id="drop1">Drop region 1</div>
<div class="droppable" id="drop2">Drop region 2</div>

<div class="draggable" id="drag1">Drag 1</div>
<div class="draggable" id="drag2">Drag 2</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$( "#drag1" ).draggable();
$( "#drag2" ).draggable();

$( "#drop1" ).droppable({
  drop: function() {
    if ($(this).attr("id") == "drag1") {
        alert("drag1 was dropped on drop1");
      } else {
      alert("something else was dropped on drop1");
      }
    }
});
$( "#drop2" ).droppable({
  drop: function() {
    alert( "dropped on drop2" );
  }
});
```

When either #drag1 or #drag2 are dropped on #drop1, it runs the else{}...

Comment: **ID of an element must be unique** so use `drag1` and `drop2` as classes instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the [`drop` event callback](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-drop), `this` referred to the droppable element (in this case, `#drop1`), which is why the `if` conditional statement wasn't working as expected.

In order to get the `id` of the element that was dropped, access the element using `ui.draggable` within the [`drop` event callback](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-drop):

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/s3oyvzdr/)

```
$("#drop1").droppable({
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        if (ui.draggable.attr("id") === "drag1") {
            // ...
        }
    }
});
```